# Difference Between "$\forall x \exists y$" and "$\exists y \forall x$"

Tags: logic, quantifiers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Confused between Nested Quantifiers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64500/confused-between-nested-quantifiers)

I asked the question about two sentences.
 [interpreting mixed quantifier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145553/interpreting-mixed-quantifier)

But, I don't know the meaning difference between
$$∀x∃y(\text{Cube}(x) → (\text{Tet}(y) ∧ \text{LeftOf}(x, y))),$$ and
$$∃y∀x(\text{Cube}(x) → (\text{Tet}(y) ∧ \text{LeftOf}(x, y))),$$

"Every cube is to the left of a tetrahedron"
"There is a tetrahedron that is to the right of every cube"

I think these sentences have same meaning.

Is it wrong? please give me your opinion.

Comment: The difference between "for every x there is a y such that..." and "there is a y such that for every x ..." is the difference between "Everyone is loved by someone" and "Someone loves everyone."

Comment: A better translation of the first sentence is "Every cube is to the left of **some** tetrahedron", to make it clear that it is not necessarily the *same* tetrahedron that works for every cube; whereas in the second sentence, the *same* tetrahedron must act as witness for every cube.

Comment: Related: [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/64500/742).

Answer (score 4):

Let’s look at a simpler example, where we assume that the variables range over real numbers: $\forall y\exists x(x+y=0)$ and $\exists x\forall y(x+y=0)$. The first says that every real number has an additive inverse, which is true. The second says that there is some particular real number $-$ call it $z$, say $-$ such that $z+y=0$ no matter what $y$ is; that’s clearly false.

In general you cannot reverse $\forall$ and $\exists$.

Answer (score 3):

The two sentences in your question do not have the same meaning: consider an infinite sequence
$$\text{Cube}\qquad\text{Tetrahedron}\qquad\text{Cube}\qquad\text{Tetrahedron}\qquad\cdots$$
Every cube is to the left of a tetrahedron, but there is no tetrahedron that is to the right of every cube.

Comment: I was about to write almost exactly the same answer. Ha!

Comment: @Alex: $\text{ }$:)

Comment: ..I constructed your example in Tarski's world. But it says that the both sentences are true..... http://thehjh.com/tarski.png